# How do I drill down by value in a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that sums a boolean column (so 1 = yes, 0 = no). I want to be able to double-click in a cell and get just those rows that have a value of 1 for the column. Instead, when I double-click, I get all rows. I've tried updating the column so that null = no, but I get the same result. Is there a way to do what I'm looking for? I want to avoid a VBA solution.

[Here's the source data for the pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87nVK.png)

[Here's option 1 for the pivot table. Department and Month are row filters. Sum of Reportable Boolean is the value. There are no column filters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMZyU.png)
For option 1, when I drill down into, say Department A+October, I get records 1, 3, and 4, but I only want to get record 1 (since that's the only one where Reportable Boolean= 1).

[Here's option 2 for the pivot table. Department and Month are still row filters, but now Reportable Boolean is a Column filter and Count of ID is the value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS1Q6.png) When I drill down into Department A + October + Reportable, I get just record 1, as I'd expect.

So option 2 *should* work, but it looks really messy once I have multiple columns ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wePSA.png)).

I've tried slicers, but I'm getting the same results when I drill down.

What I really want is something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jCCL.png), where I can double-click in a cell and get just the records that count towards that metric.

Comment: How about inserting a Slicer? Could you provide a screenshot about the PivotTable and the result you want?

Comment: So far slicers haven't helped. I added screenshots which should hopefully clarify what I'm working with.